# What is the right way to compare two strings and find the total qty of unequal chars?

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'm trying to **compare two strings**(Tx & Rx data) and find the ***quantity of unequal chars***.

With the help of the following code, I managed to get the quantity,

```
string TxData = "00001111";
string RxData = "00000000";

int distorted = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < TxData.Length; i++)
{
    if (TxData[i] != RxData[i])
    distorted++;
}
Console.Write("Distorted Bits (qty) : {0}", distorted);
```

**Result:**

Distorted Bits (qty) : 4

---

But I'm very curious to know if there's any better way to do this task?

Thanks for your time...:)

Comment: Out of interest, what will you do if RxData is shorter than TxData?

Comment: Good Point, This is just a simple exaple, I havent really included any error handling....

Comment: Will they always be 0s and 1s?

Comment: Are you actually comparing strings here or simply converting binary to a string representation and doing the comparison? It looks like what you need is to simply [XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zkacc7k1.aspx) the bytes.

Comment: Yes, It's Binary data,it'll be 1s & 0s..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they're always the same length:

```
int distorted = TxData.Zip(RxData, (a,b) => a == b ? 0 : 1).Sum();
```

Comment: Hey, Zip, I didn't know that one.

Comment: Alternatively: `TxData.Zip(RxData, (a,b) => a != b).Count(x => x)`

Comment: *"If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them."* You could count the number of equals and subtract from the length of the longer to find the total difference for uneven lengths.

Answer (score 3):

I like okrumnows answer by its simplisity, but assuming that you really already have bytes (or int) and don't need to convert them to string in the first place, you would probably be better of doing something like:

```
int myMethod(byte byte1, byte byte2)
{
    //byte1 = Convert.ToByte("10010101",2);
    //byte2 = Convert.ToByte("10011101",2);
    byte xorvalue = (byte)( byte1 ^ byte2);
    return NumberOfSetBits(xorvalue);
}

private static int NumberOfSetBits(uint i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

This will be much faster.

Comment: from [Bit Twiddling Hacks - Counting bits set, in parallel](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel)

Comment: The input to `NumberOfSetBits` should be unsigned, else the MSB won't be treated correctly. The reason for this is that signed ints use an arithmetic shift. This isn't a problem in your example, since bytes can't reach the MSB of a 32 bit int.